# Receiving Empty Response for more users in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I have a scenario recorded in Jmeter.

Login -> Home Page -> Click on the link to open Page A -> Page A opened -> Click on the tab to open Page B -> Page B opened -> Log off

1. I executed above scenario with 5 users, Ramp up 20 sec, Loop Count Forever, Scheduler Duration 300 seconds.
   [Less User Thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHatC.png)

All of the samples were Pass. (Screen shot attached)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM2S0.jpg)

2. I executed with 10 users, Ramp up 20 sec, Loop Count Forever, Scheduler Duration 600 seconds.
   [10 Users Thread][3]

This was also successful. (Screen shot attached)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg5eP.jpg)

3. I increased users to 40, Ramp up 80 and checked Loop Count Forever(Scheduler not selected)
   [Failed Thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz89v.jpg)

Samples started failing after some 25 users. (Screen shot attached)
[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu80h.jpg)

Response Data is empty for the requested Target page and response code is 200(Page A). (Screen shot attached)[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBbzM.jpg)

Response code is 500 for Page B. (Screen shot attached)[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAEA4.jpg)

I have increased the heapsize, also executed script from command prompt.
What could be the issue?

[JavascriptError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn2Bt.jpg)

After some research I got to know that, i have to use Web drivers. How can i integrate to Web driver samplers to my original scripts.

Comment: you need to show server log to understand why it failed

Comment: error 500 is a server side error. So you need to see if you hit a bug or bottleneck on server side, not on client. Or maybe you are not sending correct requests. nothing to do with JMeter resources memory, etc) though

Comment: i will upload screenshot in couple of hours and  @ Kiril S , two page which i am facing issue, consumes tokens, cookies, messageid etc. Question is when it can give proper result for less user why i am receiving server error when i increase the users. suppose if i have 20 users that created a connection and started receiving response(tokens etc) , is there will be chance that those request consuming other tokens(which is not intend to that user or session or connection). i know i am being dumb here.

Comment: @user7294900,  Kiril S. 
When i debugged, i found that its not logging after some time(i had put assertions before login and after login). Please see the screen shot. i am getting 'Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.'  in jmeter. How can i resolve this.

Comment: JavascriptError screenshot has nothing to do with your issue, and is not an issue on its own. Developers of your web page added that section in case some user doesn't have a javascript enabled on their browser. It's part of the page source

Comment: Result2 screenshot shows that response 500 was returned. It's always server that sends 500. Result1 shows red line with empty response, but from that screenshot it's hard to tell why... In general I agree with other people: in its present form the question is not answerable. You need to learn basics (e.g. HTTP error codes, `<noscript>` section on web page), and then come up with more specific concrete questions...